# How to avoid auto rounding down small double number in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, double, rounding, precision

I have this function (Written in Java) that returns a small double number (1e-6, 1e-9 etc). My other service in scala is consuming this one and is supposed to use the value as it. However the value always gets returned as 0e-10 (which is zero), even though in my JUnit the value is being returned correctly.
The datatype I'm using on my Java portion is Double, not double as I need it to be an Optional as well. Though I'm not sure if that has anything to do with this, just want to provide as much details as possible.
The code snippet:

The method that generates small number

```
private Optional<Double> getSmallNumber(InputObject obj) {
 if(obj meets certain condition)
  return Optional.of(0.00000000001)
}
```

The method that creates and returns the object

```
public JavaObject javaObjectGenerator(InputObject obj){
 return JavaObjectBuilder.setSmallNumber(getSmallNumber(obj)).
 ...
 .build();
}
```

Let's say this "SmallNumber" is just an attribute of my Java object. This Java object is then passed onto and consumed by my other Scala module. I expect to get 0.00000000001 when reading "SmallNumber" but it always gets round downed to 0e-10.

Comment: Though floating point (double) does not have a precision, maybe somewhere a precision 5 (scale -5) is applied in marshalling causing a 0.0.

Comment: Where are you losing the number? can you share a code snippet that loses it?

Comment: @JoopEggen Interestingly I tried precision 3 and it got passed down to scala as it, no rounding whatsoever. I'm still trying to figure out the root cause as I need a much smaller number though.

Comment: @TomerShetah I added the snippet to my post. Basically the java portion acts like an object builder, where it generates all the attributes and passes the final object to the scala module. I think it starts losing precision when the java portion is part of the scala module as a library. It acts completely different compared to its tested behaviour in JUnit.

Comment: @user3128826 is it because you are reading only 10 digits and you setting 1 after 10 zeros? So when it prints it is rounded to 0? Can you try to print the number after you call `getSmallNumber` to check it is not 0? Please try to multiply it by 100000 let's say just to make sure it is not 0. Which database are you using? Can it be that the DB is rounding it to 0?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like this is just a consequence of the number formatting, the underlying representation doesn't change

```
val d = 0.00000000001
println(d) //prints 1.0E-11
println(f"$d%.12f") //prints 0.000000000010
```

Comment: It actually rounds down the number to 0 as it shows in the database.

Comment: As I show here, the number isn't rounded down. Maybe your database rounds the number down for some reason, but your initial question doesn't mention a database at all. For people to help you, you need to show exactly what you did, and what results you're getting. If the problem is that an unexpected number is returned from a database query, show how it's inserted, how it's queried, and how you see the result.